# My variable keeps getting a syntax error. What should i do

Tags: python, syntax-error

the variable x always shows up as a syntax error. It means number of prime numbers to be generated

```
    x=501
    while x<1 or x>500:
        NoNos=int(input("Number of Prime Numbers"))
        if x<1:
            print("The number has to be greater than 1")
        if x>500:
            print("The number has to be lesser than 500")
    PrimeNo=2
    PrimeNos=[]
    While not x==0:
        if PrimeNo==2:
            PrimeNos=PrimeNos+[PrimeNo]
            x=x-1
            PrimeNo=PrimeNo+1
            continue
        for divisor in the range (2,PrimeNo-1):
            if not PrimeNo%divisor=0:
                x=x-1
                PrimeNos=PrimeNos+[PrimeNo]
    print(PrimeNos)
```

Comment: its in the line while not x==0: btw. The earlier code was executed perfectly

Comment: That "PrimeNo%divisor=0" looks suspicious. It should probably be a "==".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ python test.py
  File "test.py", line 11
    While not x==0:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is a bug in Python. The caret should be pointing to the capital 'W' in 'While'.  You must spell 'while' with all lowercase letters.

You have some other typos as well:

```
   File "test.py", line 17
    for divisor in the range (2,PrimeNo-1):
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here the caret should point at the 'the', which should just be removed.

```
  File "test.py", line 18
    if not PrimeNo%divisor=0:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This time the caret is in the right place!  '=' needs to be '=='.

After I make all those changes your program still does not *work*, but the remaining problems do not seem to be syntax.

(I filed http://bugs.python.org/issue23518 on the misplaced carets.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. However as you mentioned, it still docent work. It keeps saying that the value has to be less than 500 no matter what i enter. That part was working earlier on and used to return that it has to be greater than 1 when it wasn't but now all it ever returns is has to be lesser than 500

Comment: I regret to say we are not a general debugging service. I was willing to help you with the cases where the incorrectly-positioned carets misled you about the actual problem, but as far as the remaining bugs go, you need to learn to figure them out for yourself.  I will offer one hint: look again at which variable is set by the `input` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some errors in your code

1. While => while
2. the range => range
3. PrimeNo%divisor=0: => PrimeNo%divisor==0:

=======================================================================

```
x=501
while x<1 or x>500:
    NoNos=int(input("Number of Prime Numbers"))
    if x<1:
        print("The number has to be greater than 1")
    if x>500:
        print("The number has to be lesser than 500")
PrimeNo=2
PrimeNos=[]
while not x==0:
    if PrimeNo==2:
        PrimeNos=PrimeNos+[PrimeNo]
        x=x-1
        PrimeNo=PrimeNo+1
        continue
    for divisor in range (2,PrimeNo-1):
        if not PrimeNo%divisor == 0:
            x=x-1
            PrimeNos=PrimeNos+[PrimeNo]
print(PrimeNos)
```

Comment: Wow thank you. However, i thought that my program would run after that. Whatever value I enter it always returns that the value has to be lesser than 500. How do i solve this ?